# Some trouble when exchange two elements in a python list

Tags: python

I have wrote a class named edge like this:

```
class Edge:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    ...
```

then I generate some edges

```
a1 = Edge()
a2 = Edge()
a3 = Edge()
graph = [a1,a2,a3]
```

now I want to exchange the a1,a3. so I write:

```
graph[0],graph[2] = graph[2],graph[0]
```

I think the graph has been exchanged like this.

```
>>>graph
>>>[a3,a2,a1]
```

but result is the graph is still the origin `graph>>>[a1,a2,a3]`
so I would like to ask why this happend? Is there any other solutions to exchange the graph?

Comment: Can you write a really short code snippet where this actually happens? If not, then maybe graph or edge override some operator. It works as expected with  l = [1, 2, 3]; l[2], l[0] = l[0], l[2]; print l

Comment: I believe the list elements were swapped, but something else is wrong. How do you tell the difference between a1, a2 and a3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
graph = [graph[i] for i in [2, 1, 0]]
```

or for the more general case:

```
def swap(g, i, j):
    tmp = g[i]
    g[i]= g[j]
    g[j] = tmp

graph = swap(graph, i, j)
```

Comment: Is this how you would swap two elements in the list if the list has 1000 elements?

Comment: This seems very wasteful to me.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected.

```
class Edge:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pred = 0
        self.succ = 0
        self.weight = 1
        self.name = ''

    def __init__(self, p, s, w, strName):
        self.pred = p
        self.succ = s
        self.weight = w
        self.name = strName

a1 = Edge(0,1,1,'a1')
a2 = Edge(1,2,3,'a2')
a3 = Edge(2,3,5,'a3')


a = [a1, a2, a3]
print(a[0].name)
a[1], a[0] = a[0], a[1]
print(a[0].name)
```

The output is
a1
a2
as expected.